# Disable hoover, re-enable but click wont work again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im using bootstrap modal to display some information, when i click the first item the modal comes down but the item stays in hoover, and i dont want it. So i made js and got around it, but it wont activate the click again on that item.

So the js makes the hover disapear and makes it appear again, but it wont let me click to open the modal again.

```js
function setHover() {
    $('.chata')
    .css({ 'opacity': '0' })
    .off('mouseover mouseleave click')
    .on({
        mouseover: function () {
            $(this).css({ 'opacity': '1' });
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).css({ 'opacity': '0' });
        },
        click: function () {
            $('.chata').off('mouseover mouseleave click');
            $(this).css({ 'opacity': '0' });
            setHover();
        }
    });
}


setHover();
```

```css
.overlayy {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
}


    .overlayy:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }

.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.imageee {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 projectos text-center containeer">

        <img src="assets/img/cofre.png" class="imageee">
        <a id="pop1" href="#" class="poppers overlayy chata"><img src="assets/img/address.png"></a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content border border-light rounded-0">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Carteira Portuguesa</h5>
                        <div class="modelxclose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Conteudo vai
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer opacityPulse-css">
                        <p class="font-weight-bold modelpfooter">We Made it. - 2018</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 projectos text-center containeer self_clear">

        <img src="assets/img/cofre.png" class="imageee">
        <a id="pop2" href="#" class="poppers overlayy"><img src="assets/img/address.png"></a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content border border-light rounded-0">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Carteira Portuguesa</h5>
                        <div class="modelxclose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Conteudo vai
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer opacityPulse-css">
                        <p class="font-weight-bold modelpfooter">We Made it. - 2018</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 projectos text-center containeer self_clear">

        <img src="assets/img/cofre.png" class="imageee">
        <a id="pop3" href="#" class="poppers overlayy"><img src="assets/img/address.png"></a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="3" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content border border-light rounded-0">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Carteira Portuguesa</h5>
                        <div class="modelxclose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Conteudo vai
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer opacityPulse-css">
                        <p class="font-weight-bold modelpfooter">We Made it. - 2018</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 projectos text-center containeer self_clear">

        <img src="assets/img/cofre.png" class="imageee">
        <a id="pop4" href="#" class="poppers overlayy"><img src="assets/img/address.png"></a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="4" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content border border-light rounded-0">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Carteira Portuguesa</h5>
                        <div class="modelxclose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Conteudo vai
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer opacityPulse-css">
                        <p class="font-weight-bold modelpfooter">We Made it. - 2018</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#exampleModalLong"` to your links, like this:

```
<a id="pop1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" href="#" class="poppers overlayy chata">Image here</a>
```

Replace the target with the modal you want each link to open.
Also, do not give multiple modals the same id, ids need to be unique.

https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/1wktbzfc/